# i can console.log(data) in getCurrency function but can't asign data to setCurrency .it does'nt work

Tags: javascript, fetch

i can console.log value of data in getCurrency funuction.but when i try to put data into setCurrency and get it from currency it doesn't work.its just empty object then.

```
import React ,{useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import TranslateForm from './translateComponent';

const Main = () => {

    const API_KEY = 'b8533a4d2a2297728b70';

    const [rcurrency, setRcurrency] = useState('USD');
    const [ccurrency, setCcurrency] = useState('LKR');
    const [query, setQuery] = useState();
    const [currency, setCurrency] = useState({});

    useEffect(() => {
        setCurrency(getCurrency());
        console.log(currency);
    },[]);

    useEffect(
        () => {
            getQuery();
        },[query]
    );
    

    const getCurrency = async() => {
        const responce = await fetch(`https://free.currconv.com/api/v7/currencies?apiKey=${API_KEY}`);
        const data = await responce.json();
        console.log(data);
        setCurrency(data);
    }
   

    const getQuery = async() => {
        const responce = await fetch(`https://free.currconv.com/api/v7/convert?q=${rcurrency}_${ccurrency},${ccurrency}_${rcurrency}&compact=ultra&apiKey=${API_KEY}`);
        const qdata = await responce.json();
        setQuery(qdata[Object.keys(qdata)[0]]);
        console.log(query);
    }

    return(
        <div>
            <TranslateForm/>
        </div>
    );

}



export default Main;
```

Comment: Your `getCurrency` is `async` but you are not awaiting it when calling `setCurrency(getCurrency())` Thus, what you really do is passing a `Promise<void>` to `setCurrency` which won't work. Why are you even doing `setCurrency(getCurrency())` when you already call `setCurrency` inside of `getCurrency`?

Comment: yeah, that's a mistake.Thank you for correcting...!

Answer (score 0):

Actually the issue is your function is not returning any data in order to set that in the setCurrency method.
Either set data in your getCurrency() method or return the data from getCurrency and set in useEffect().

```
useEffect(() => {
        const respCurrency = getCurrency();
        respCurrency.then((data)=>{
          setCurrency(respCurrency);
       })
        console.log(currency); // this will always give you default value
    },[]);

    const getCurrency = async() => {
        const responce = await fetch(`https://free.currconv.com/api/v7/currencies?apiKey=${API_KEY}`);
        const data = await responce.json();
        console.log(data);
        setCurrency(data);
        return data;
    }
return(
        <div>
    Data : JSON.stringify(currency) // Your currency logging
            <TranslateForm/>
        </div>
    );
```

Also since getCurrency is an async funtion it will most probably be returning you a promise object.So use .then() method to assign to the setCurrency method.
Try consoling currency now in your render method you will get the data.

I hope this works.
Thanks

Comment: Why are you calling `setCurrency`twice? You should either (preferrable) remove it from the body of `getCurrency` or don't call it again in the resolve handler of the promise ... Furthermore I strongly suggest, not to mix `async/await` with `.then().catch()` Choose the form you like better and stick with it. Anything else will lead to confuions and probably errors ..

Comment: @derpirscher It's just for the understanding purpose since he seems to be a newbie but I have mentioned clearly above use either of them return value either from function and then  set the value or directly set the value in the function itself. Thanks